# How to add new row to ngx-datatable with input data from user?

Tags: javascript, angular, ngx-datatable

How can I add a new row to an `ngx-datatable` based on user input?

I add an empty row like this:

```
addRow() {
  this.rows.unshift({unique_id: '<em>empty</em>', name: '<em>empty</em>'});
  this.rows = this.rows.slice();
}
```

But how can I control the row so a user can add data to that row?

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? Also, I tried your code above to at least add an empty row to start off, and it added it to the top of the list. How would I add it to the bottom of the list? Thanks!

Comment: I did not found an ok solution. You can add it at the end with `this.rows.push(data));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your component.html to loop over all labels

```html
<ngx-datatable
  #mydatatable
  class="material"
  [headerHeight]="50"
  [limit]="5"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [footerHeight]="50"
  [rowHeight]="'auto'"
  [rows]="rows"
  [scrollbarH]="true">
  <ngx-datatable-column *ngFor="let label of labels" [name]="label.name" [prop]="label.prop">
    <ng-template ngx-datatable-cell-template let-rowIndex="rowIndex" let-value="value" let-row="row">
      <span
        title="double Click here "
        (dblclick)="editCell(label.prop, rowIndex)"
        *ngIf="!editing[rowIndex + '-' + label.prop]"
      >
        {{ value }}
      </span>
      <input
        autofocus
        (blur)="updateValue($event, label.prop, rowIndex)"
        (keyup.enter)="updateValue($event, label.prop, rowIndex)"
        *ngIf="editing[rowIndex+ '-' + label.prop]"
        [type]="label.inputType"
        class="form-control"
        [value]="value"
      />
    </ng-template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Then add these methods into your component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mycomponent',
  templateUrl: './mycomponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./mycomponent.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent{
  editing = {};
  rows = [];
  labels = [];
  
  // call to update cell value
  updateValue(event, cell, rowIndex) {
    this.editing[rowIndex + '-' + cell] = false;
    this.rows[rowIndex][cell] = event.target.value;
    this.rows = [...this.rows];
  }

  // call on double click in cell
  editCell(cell, rowIndex) {
    this.editing = {};
    this.editing[rowIndex + '-' + cell] = true;
  } 
}
```